# Rails application hosted on slice eating up memory like giant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slicehost

I am working on a normal CRUD application using rails 3.0.9

I have deployed the application on the Slicehost (RAM 512 MB). But when i access the application within 5 mins it takes up all the memory & application crashes.

Can anybody will help me out here?

Comment: I know dude, But waiting for some answers for this serious issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run top, then hit 'shift+m' to see which proc is eating up the RAM.

It may not be the rails app, but rather MySQL or Apache launching too many processes .. too many mogrels if deployed using mongrels.

Also check out this page for rails RAM usage shrinking: http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_resource_control_and_optimization_options

And this page for Apache / MySQL shrinking: http://chrisjohnston.org/2008/configuring-a-lightweight-apache-mysql-install-on-debian-ubuntu